# Android 4.4: access smartphone as USB memory

Tags: usb, android, usb-storage

When connecting my old Android 2.3-based smartphone with a PC, I get a notification to enable it as USB memory. When I try the same with my new Moto G (Android 4.4.2), I don't get such a notification. There only are options to enable MTP or PTP, but I don't want my Moto G turn into a media player but just an USB memory stick. Has this USB memory option been removed between Android 2.3 and 4.4 or does the Moto G simply not support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its been removed for most of the 4.x series (since ICS) in favour of MTP. The only real way to get the old MTP mode is to install CM or some other third party rom which supports it.

Comment: So I can't install any self-developed application on it?

Comment: I've pushed applications to my phone through other means and have side-loaded before. You can still access the flash memory as MTP, or download the APK directly. You're just not using it as a USB storage device. You can copy over the apk from your system using mtp, and run it from a file manager, after you have turned on non marketplace apps. There's nothing that correlates mass storage compliance with sideloading apps.

Answer (score 0):

Mass Storage Mode has been removed from all subsequent Android version. Google doesn't want to pay MS any more Copyright $!  One does not require any special ROM to get it back but it does require root.

I have a Galaxy S4 running stock TLS 4.3 , rooted, and use USB Mass Storage Enabler by Mohammad Abu-Garbeyyeh.  SyncToy works flawlessly.